# Bugzilla: closed-fixed bugs: how to stop further comments being added to bug (due to freezing for migration to JIRA)

Tags: comments, bugzilla

In bugzilla 2.22.7, it is possible to add further comments to a closed-fixed/resolved bug. I would like to deactivate this feature as I want to migrate bugs as they get closed to JIRA and not have people updating the old system.

I could hotwire/custom hack the bugzilla Perl code to do this, eventually when I've understood it, but just wondered if there was a better way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hardwire/hack:

in the show_bug.cgi bugzilla code, modify it, with the equivalent of the following pseudocode:

if bugzilla title starts with [JIRAnnnnn] then
use the disable attribute in html forms, e.g. as described in:
  [How to make a greyed-out HTML form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789844/how-to-make-a-greyed-out-html-form)

end if

but i also need an automation to write the [JIRAnnnnn] prefix into the title of the bugzilla record, once the JIRA entry has been created

Also add a html wallpaper background to indicate migrated